# draw layout widget on libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am almost new on LibGDX
I need to draw an overlay on my game like this one:

[image]

There is a background, 2 text and a botton

I would like to draw it using a class and reuse it in many part of my game.
I try to extend a "stack" class but is not good.
Also I would like to add the class into a table so probably I need to extend an actor

Can somebody tell me witch layout/class/widget is the best to achive this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your layout will be similar to the image you posted, you could use a Table for that.

https://javadoc.io/static/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx/1.11.0/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Table.html

I often use nested Tables if I need to span multiple columns/rows instead of trying to do everything in one Table. This makes things easier to work with IMO.

For the example image you posted, you could use two tables. Table1 is the entire widget and Table2 has the two Label (text) items. Then you can set the background on Table1, which will place the background behind everything in the table.

To layout each item in the Table, the Cell (part of LibGDX's Table) is typically used for this. You can set size, alignment, padding, spacing, etc. on each cell of the table to get the layout you want.

For example, to add a padding of 20 to the left side of the button:

```
table1.getCell(button).padLeft(20);
```

Here is the API for Cell.

https://javadoc.io/static/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx/1.11.0/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Cell.html